# How to stream video from backend (NodeJS) to LiveKit room using JWT?

Tags: node.js, jwt, livekit

There are not NodeJS SDK for backend and I can't find any ways to start streaming with JWT (by CLI or Go SDK). It need key and secret, but i can provide only access token JWT.

I tried use CLI for streaming, but it works only with api key and secret.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/livekit-server-sdk

Answer (score 0):

LiveKit doesn't have a node SDK at the moment but they have a number of server side "client" SDKs. The most popular one is the python SDK: https://github.com/livekit/python-sdks

From that SDK you can add a participant into the room that has access to raw audio and video frames which can be used in gstreamer via the appsrc plugin.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/livekit-server-sdk